# Slow Performance with NamedParameterJdbcTemplate

Tags: java, sql, oracle, spring-data-jpa, jdbctemplate

I have a Spring5 application using `NamedParameterJdbcTemplate` to fetch data from OracleDB.

When I execute the same query from intellij DB console I get the result in 1.5 seconds but when I execute the same query from the Java application using
`jdbcTemplate.queryForList(query, params);` it takes 90 seconds

Here is the DBconfigration class:

```
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories("com.xxxx.xxx.relational.repositories")
@PropertySource(value = "classpath:jdbc.properties")
@ComponentScan
@EnableTransactionManagement
@Import(RestTemplateConfig.class)
public class RelationalConfig {

    @Bean(destroyMethod = "close")
    public BasicDataSource dataSource(@Value("${jdbc.driverClassName}") String driverClassName,
            @Value("${jdbc.url}") String url, @Value("${jdbc.username}") String username,
            @Value("${jdbc.password}") String password) {
        BasicDataSource ds = new BasicDataSource();
        ds.setDriverClassName(driverClassName);
        ds.setUrl(url);
        ds.setUsername(username);
        ds.setPassword(password);
        return ds;
    }

    @Bean
    HibernateJpaVendorAdapter hibernateJpaVendorAdapter() {
        return new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
    }

    @Bean
    @Autowired
    LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory(BasicDataSource dataSource,
            HibernateJpaVendorAdapter vendor, @Value("${hibernate.dialect}") String dialect,
            @Value("${jdbc.schema}") String schema) {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactoryBean = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource);
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendor);
        Properties jpaProperties = new Properties();

        jpaProperties.put("hibernate.dialect", dialect);
        jpaProperties.put("hibernate.default_schema", schema);
//        jpaProperties.put("hibernate.jdbc.fetch_size", 200);
//        jpaProperties.put("hibernate.connection.pool_size", 10);
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setJpaProperties(jpaProperties);
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setPackagesToScan("com.xxx.xxx.relational.entities");
        return entityManagerFactoryBean;
    }


    @Bean
    @Autowired
    JpaTransactionManager transactionManager(EntityManagerFactory factory) {
        return new JpaTransactionManager(factory);
    }


    @Bean
    @Autowired
    NamedParameterJdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate(DataSource dataSource) {
        JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
        jdbcTemplate.setFetchSize(200);
        return new NamedParameterJdbcTemplate(jdbcTemplate);
    }


    @Bean
    @Autowired
    SiblingsRepo<LegDTO> legSiblingsRepo(LegRepository legRepo) {
        return new SiblingsRepo<LegDTO>() {
            @Override
            public Optional<LegDTO> byNext(LegDTO next) {
                return legRepo.findByNextLegId(next.getId());
            }

            @Override
            public Optional<LegDTO> byId(Integer id) {
                return legRepo.findById(id);
            }

            @Override
            public LegDTO save(LegDTO sibling) {
                return legRepo.save(sibling);
            }
        };
    }


    @Bean
    @Autowired
    SiblingsRepo<JourneyDTO> journeySiblingsRepo(JourneyRepository journeyRepo) {
        return new SiblingsRepo<JourneyDTO>() {
            @Override
            public Optional<JourneyDTO> byNext(JourneyDTO next) {
                return journeyRepo.findByNextJourneyId(next.getId());
            }

            @Override
            public Optional<JourneyDTO> byId(Integer id) {
                return journeyRepo.findById(id);
            }

            @Override
            public JourneyDTO save(JourneyDTO sibling) {
                return journeyRepo.save(sibling);
            }
        };
    }

    @Bean
    public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertyConfig() {
        return new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
    }
}
```

Here is the query:

```
String q = "select journeyid, extid, extccuid
        from ACTIVE_JOURNEY_VIEW
        WHERE coalesce(ata, nextJourneyEtd, sysdate + 1) > sysdate
          AND ((organizationid = :orgId AND deleted = 0)
            OR organizationid = :orgId
            OR enclosingHire_organizationId = :orgId
            OR gln_orig_organizationid = :orgId
            OR originFacilityId in (
                select facilityid
                from v_FacilityAndBbrOrg
                where bbrorgid = :orgId
                  and (nvl(atd, etd), activeEndDate) overlaps (fromDate, toDate))
            OR gln_dest_organizationid = :orgId
            OR destinationFacilityId in (
                select facilityid
                from v_FacilityAndBbrOrg
                where bbrorgid = :orgId
                  and (nvl(atd, etd), activeEndDate) overlaps (fromDate, toDate))
            )";

protected <T> List<T> query(String key, RowMapper<T> mapper, Object... kvs) {
    Map<String, Object> params = map(kvs);
    return  jdbcTemplate.queryForList(q, params);
}
```

Comment: Are you connected to the same db server from intellij and your application?

Comment: Yes both connecting to the same dB server

Comment: Are you fetching the complete result in the console?

Comment: yes the execute the same query on both  java application and console and I get the same result but a very different response time

Comment: Comparing apples and oranges. What happens is that you also have a rowmapper which turns the result into objects. Depending on the amount of data this takes a lot of time. Also what time are you measuring? Only the db execution or the rendering of an HTTP page.

Comment: @M.Deinum is there any suggestion to improve it?

Answer (score 1):

Please, keep in mind that behind the scenes probably IntelliJ is performing some kind of optimization when running your query - prefetching data slices, using caches, etcetera. For these and other reasons this kind of tools will usually offer a better performance that when the application run as pure Java code.

Having said that, in order to improve your query, you can do several things.

On one hand, review your sql, I think it can be improved in different ways:

- Get rid of `IN` clauses, they offer typically a very poor performance. Use JOINS or maybe, in your example, `EXISTS` clauses instead.
- Probably it will be advisable for the following columns to be indexed (be careful in any case, these are a lot columns, and the indexes maintenance can be expensive and can affect the performance when running insert, update and delete operations, try to find a balance between queries and DML operations):

  - organizationid
  - enclosingHire_organizationId
  - gln_orig_organizationid
  - gln_dest_organizationid
  - bbrorgid
  - facilityid
- You are applying functions like `nvl` and `coalesce` to your dates: I am afraid that they seems necessary, but be aware that it will probably prevent the use of any index created over that columns. The use of many `OR`s sometimes is not optimal as well.
- I think you can simplify the queries related with the `v_FacilityAndBbrOrg` table.

In summary, please, try to use a query similar to this:

```java
String q = "select journeyid, extid, extccuid
        from ACTIVE_JOURNEY_VIEW
        WHERE coalesce(ata, nextJourneyEtd, sysdate + 1) > sysdate
          AND ((organizationid = :orgId AND deleted = 0)
            OR organizationid = :orgId
            OR enclosingHire_organizationId = :orgId
            OR gln_orig_organizationid = :orgId
            OR gln_dest_organizationid = :orgId
            OR EXISTS (
                select 1 
                from v_FacilityAndBbrOrg
                where bbrorgid = :orgId
                  and (facilityid = originFacilityId OR facilityid = destinationFacilityId)
                  and (nvl(atd, etd), activeEndDate) overlaps (fromDate, toDate)
            )
          )";
```

In addition, try to benchmark your application with different fetch sizes. You indicated `200` records with seems quite reasonable. In any way, of course, depending on the available memory for your application and other aspects like the row size, etcetera, try to increase that number: any amount up to `1000` records can be good enough.

Finally, try to measure when your application is consuming your time, whether querying the database, obtaining the results and converting your records, serializing to JSON or rendering a server side page. You have several options for this purpose, of course, but at a first glance, using a simple tool like [`StopWatch`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/util/StopWatch.html) can be useful to detect, roughly, *grosso modo*, possible bottlenecks.

Answer (score 0):

i set the max fetch size like this. Integer.MAX_VALUE = 2147483647. call goes from 4 secs to ms

```
@Bean(name = "spiderman")
public JdbcTemplate spiderJdbcTemplate(@Qualifier("spidermanDataSource") DataSource spidermanDataSource) {
    JdbcTemplate jdbc = new JdbcTemplate(spidermanDataSource);
    jdbc.setFetchSize(Integer.MAX_VALUE);

    return jdbc;
}
```